# Aspectj - pointcut on threads during runtime in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to use Aspectj and I can't find the right command for my purpose. I need to use Aspectj on run-time because I have a thread that opens from a third party jar which isn't closed and stuck my program.
I'm trying to use Aspectj to make a function before every thread's starting on run-time, which means before every funcion that return a new thread. That's the command I'm trying to use which isn't working. I'm using java annotation:

```java
@Before("execution(public java.lang.Thread com.a.b..*(..))")
```

Does anyone know what's the right way to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: You will likely get more help if you provide complete example code for what you are trying to accomplish, and identify what frameworks and spring components you are using. Are you using xml files to configure your application context, or are you using Java classes annotated with @Configuration, etc.

Comment: @mangotang, the user was talking about AspectJ, he never mentioned Spring or Spring AOP. What makes you think he uses Spring? But still the request for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is valid, I second it.

Comment: There are plenty of possible causes why this would not work, e.g. (a) using compile-time weaving on your code but expecting it to work inside 3rd party libs, (b) using load-time weaving, but configuring it wrong, (c) intercepting methods which you expect to be called in the 3rd party lib but which actually are never called. Please make the problem reproduceable by means of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as @mangotang suggested. Then we can help you.